# Occurrence of a word from a set of words in a string

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

Could someone suggest the algorithm to find the occurrence of any word from the set of K words in a string?
For Example :
Set of Words: {abc,xyz}
String : **abc**defghi**abc**jklab**xyz**
Output : {0,9,17} //Starting positions of words in the string

Something better than running KMP K times !!!

Comment: Use a regex with alternation group to iterate all match objects and grab the match indices. :)

Comment: See Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: I guess KMP helps in finding the word in a string not helpful for finding occurrence of words from a set of words in a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) is intended to search for any word from given dictionary in the text.

There are [some other algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns) for this task - Commentz-Walter , Rabin–Karp (but Aho-Corasic one has better complexity for the worst case)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on an industrial scale, use a suffix tree. You store every suffix in the string, and you can then search for sub-strings in essentially O constant time, because all the sub strings are the same string with different suffixes.

However the strings need to be very long before a suffix tree justifies the complexity (they are used in reality for scanning DNA sequence data amongst other things).